# jQuery UI does not load on $("#content").load page for .button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I seem to make a mistake in the following:
html: index.html, main.html, etc
js: jQuery, jQuery UI, own.js, own_main.js

The end result should be an index page that based on a menu choice loads a html in a div.
The HTML that loads has a button element that I want to use with jQuery UI.

Index.html

```
<html lang="us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Dev</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/typ.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/typ.js"></script>
<script src="js/typ-persons.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

typ.js file

```
function currentLoc(goToLoc) {
    if (CheckLogin() == 0) {
        //Not logged in, go to main
        $("#content").load("/main.html");
        window.localStorage.globalLocation = "/main.html";
    } else {
        if (goToLoc == '') {
            console.log("No GoToLoc: " + goToLoc);
            if (window.localStorage.globalLocation == '') {
                console.log("No Global location");
                $("#content").load("/main.html");
                window.localStorage.globalLocation = "/main.html";
            } else {
                console.log("Global Location " + window.localStorage.globalLocation);
                $("#content").load(window.localStorage.globalLocation);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("GoToLoc " + goToLoc);
            $("#content").load(goToLoc);
            window.localStorage.globalLocation = goToLoc;
        }
    }
}
```

persons.html

```
<script src="js/typ-persons.js"></script>

<div class="container">

    <style>
        #toolbar {
            padding: 4px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        /* support: IE7 */
        * + html #toolbar {
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="toolbar" style="width:100%;" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <button id="btnNew" ></button>
        <button id="btnSave"></button>
        <label for="persons">Find Person by Name or ID: </label>
        <input type="text" class="input-sm" id="persons">
        <input type="hidden" id="person-id">
    </div>
</div>
```

typ-persons.js

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnNew").button({
        text: false,
        label: "New Person",
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-document"
        }
    })
   .click(function () {

   });
    $("#btnSave").button({
        text: false,
        label: "Save",
        disabled: true,
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-disk"
        }
    })
    .click(function () {

   });
});
```

On the persons page there is also an autocomplete element with json data.
This works like a charm.
The problem is that the toolbar does not get the buttons applied from the typ-persons.js.
When I add the jQuery UI to the persons.html the buttons do work and get styled as they are supposed to.
The problem then is that jQuery UI loads twice and the autocomplete drowdown disappears on mouse over.
Kind of a paradox here and I would like both to work.

Thanks for your help,
Joris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I have the hunch that your persons.html file is the main.html addressed in the code. Otherwise I can't see where do you load persons.html or what are you loading when you load main.html.
2. Why are you adding *typ-persons.js* to *persons.html*, if you already have it in your main html file? In the way it's added, there's going to be double binding on button clicks. More than once, I believe. It would work on first load and then screw button behavior for good.

EDIT: After OP clarifications, these are my suggestions.

**First**: instead of putting new JS into persons html, make it just plain html. Make sure you don't use id attributes when that content is prone to be loaded several times. In that case, it's best to use classes.

```
<div class="container">
    <style>
        #toolbar {
            padding: 4px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        /* support: IE7 */
        * + html #toolbar {
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="toolbar" style="width:100%;" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <button class="btnNew" ></button>
        <button class="btnSave"></button>
        <label for="persons">Find Person by Name or ID: </label>
        <input type="text" class="input-sm" id="persons">
        <input type="hidden" id="person-id">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Second**: since you won't load new JS in that ajax call, you need to give the new buttons their behavior somewhere, right? Try to do that **after** they're appended, using jQuery's callback. I'd reccomend you use *get* method instead of *load* to have a bit more control on new content. Instead of

```
 $("#content").load("/persons.html");
```

Try

```
$.get("/persons.html",function(responseText) {
    var newElement=jQuery(responseText);
    $("#content").append(newElement);
    $(".btnNew", newElement).button({
        text: false,
        label: "New Person",
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-document"
        }
    }).click(function () {

    });

    $(".btnSave",newElement).button({
        text: false,
        label: "Save",
        disabled: true,
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-disk"
        }
    }).click(function () {

    });

});
```

**Third**: whatever listener you need to be set on dynamic elements, delegate them to the document to avoid needing to redeclare it (with the risk of double binding). I see no examples of this in your original post, but if you have any case of click, focus, or blur listeners (to name a few) I'll include a practical example.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you. For point 1, yes, you are right, I also have a main.html file and some others, I should have changed that here to make it clear. For point 2, I've tried changing it to be in the index and in the persons.html file. (So loaded it once) that does not make any difference.

Comment: Ok, but let I still don't get it. ¿Is persons.html meant to be loaded alone or it's loaded to one div of index.html?

Comment: The index.html is the only page that gets loaded. All other pages get loaded into the 'content' div. The problem arrises with the use of Jquery UI that is loaded with the index.html. But when called upon in the js that gets loaded with the persons.html (into the div) it does not work. When I add it to the persons.html (double load of jquery ui) the buttons work but the autocomplete dropdown for a textbox then disappears when the mouse moves over it. (I know that is a result of the double loading). The problem is I need Jquery UI on index and all the other pages that get loaded into the div.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting the idea. Look, you don't need to load any JS in your dynamic html sections. Just load it all in index.html. Now, you say the problem is that some widgets don't work this way. That's because you need to change your code to do 2 things: modify your controls (such as autocomplete) to fire after the new elements join the DOM and second, modify any jQuery listeners so you delegate its trigger to the document instead of the element, which doesn't exists when you first declare ir. I'll edit my original answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was a great lesson in how to do this.